# An extra character '\' is added while adding object to JSON String

Tags: android, json

Below is my jsonString:

```
jsonString= {"date_of_birth":"17-2-1989 ","email_id":"s@s.a","fullname":"a","hp_id":"Wellcare","password":"a","phone_no":"12345","ss_no":"12345","username":"a"}
```

I wants to add "User" object to it

so I did this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("User", jsonString);
```

but I am getting this:

```
{"User":"{\"date_of_birth\":\"17-2-2015 \",\"email_id\":\"s@s.a\",\"fullname\":\"a\",\"healthplan_provider_id\":\"Wellcare\",\"password\":\"a\",\"phone_no\":\"12345\",\"social_security_no\":\"12345\",\"username\":\"a\"}"}
```

An extra character '\' is added. So I want to remove it. Please help removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add your JSON as a `String`. Add it as a `JSONObject`.

```
JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("User", new JSONObject(jsonString));
```

When you add it as a String, you lose the ability to query User properties via JSON methods. This is because the JSON parser now treats the complete object as a literal string and hence escapes all the quotes as well.

Comment: Adding a little more explanation: Notice the quote immediately after the first colon.  That's how you can tell that the entire object is being added as a single string.  The '\'s are there to allow that string to contain embedded quotes.

Comment: (plus 1): If you put it as a `String`, `JSONObject` will escape it so another parser can read this "`String`".

Comment: Hi ravi, 
I am adding jsonobjects inside a list with a loop, will this work for me? because when i am using this its taking only last object value of jsonobject.